# go build error: go tool: no such tool “link”

Tags: go

After command:

```
  go build
```

It shows an error:

```
 go tool: no such tool "link"
```

Details:
my system is windows 10 ->  64 bits

```
go version: 1.11.5 
go env -> 
set GOARCH=386
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=c:\users\john\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=386
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=E:\codigo
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GO386=sse2
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CPFLAGS=-g -02
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -02
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -02
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -02
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m32 -mtherads -fno-caret-diagnotics -Qunused-arguments -fmsessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\USers\john\ApddData\Local\temp\go-build126731998=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

I' not pretty sure what could be happening because this is the first time it happends to me, I just change my operating system(before was windows 7) and updated to windows 10 with all the recently updates.After that I install go and when I try to build my code, it shows the error

Comment: It might be help to know the full command you are running to build the go program

Comment: full command: go build

Comment: Are you able to simply run the program?

Comment: It does not build it, it shows an error after go build

Comment: Have you tried simply running the program? `go run .` within the directory root

Comment: I just tried with command: go run me/backend and it shows the same error, I tried wih: go run . too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187396/discussion-between-waymobetta-and-john-balvin-arias).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I downloaded go for 32 bits, but my machine is 64 bits, so I just download go for 64 bits and it worked