# go tool: no such tool "link"

Tags: windows, go

After upgrading Go from 1.13 to 1.15.11 using (go1.15.11.windows-amd64.msi) cannot use Go Build.. getting error

After command

> go build -o test_plugin.exe cmd/main.go

Getting error: **go tool: no such tool "link"**

My system is Windows 10 - 64 bits

```
c:\Program Files\Go>go env
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\asik\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\asik\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\asik\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\asik\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\ASIK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build756567874=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches


Go>go tool

addr2line
api
asm
buildid
cgo
compile
cover
dist
doc
fix
go_bootstrap
nm
objdump
oldlink
pack
pprof
test2json
trace
vet
```

Do I need link, is there another tool we need to use for compiling source code into an .exe?
Found the following similar question posted
[go build error: go tool: no such tool “link”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392180/go-build-error-go-tool-no-such-tool-link)

My system is 64bit and I installed go for a 64 bit, still getting the error.
Please advise!

Thanks

Comment: Try installing tdm-gcc

Comment: Yes it did remove the older version before starting the new. I can say that cause it did remove GOROOT also go from C:\Go and new files were put under "C:\Program Files\Go"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this command:

```
go build -x file.go
```

Gives this result:

```
"c:\\go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_amd64\\link.exe" -o "$WORK\\b001\\exe\\a.out.exe"
-importcfg "$WORK\\b001\\importcfg.link" -buildmode=pie
-buildid=a3yQYdmCUBlKRJRnXOtI/-ILbUkUHpKsIsmcOlKCY/LTj3Pux0FskrMdFjMcGk/a3yQYdmCUBlKRJRnXOtI
-extld=gcc "$WORK\\b001\\_pkg_.a"
```

I would check to see if that file is in that location. You should not need to
add it to the `PATH`. If that fails, I would just download this:

https://golang.org/dl/go1.16.3.windows-amd64.zip

and extract so that you are left with a path like `C:\go\bin\go.exe`.

Comment: Earlier go was in C:\Go recent installation done with "go1.15.11.windows-amd64.msi" removed go from C:\Go also GOROOT system variable and put new files in C:\Program Files\Go.

As soon as i open Visual Code I see failed output

Comment: I installed "go1.16.3.windows-amd64.msi" I see link.exe under C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
Now if i try to run go build command it complains about go.mod file


C:\stand_alone_plugin>go build -o standlone_plugin.exe cmd/main.go
cmd\main.go:12:2: no required module provides package github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 
'go help modules'

Comment: I removed 1.16 and installed 1.15 this time i was able to build.
Thank you everyone for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

That is because you didn’t deleted the previous installation and there are some conflicting.
This happens in linux when I don’t remove the previous $GOROOT(c:\go fir windows) folder.

Comment: I do not see link.exe in c:\\go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_amd64\\
I am using Telegraf as per the repo 1.15 is recommended